# Weird Multithreading Performance of Simple Benchmark (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, benchmarking

Recently I wrote a really simple code as a benchmark to see performance increase in my machine. It just creates some number of threads and divides some number of spins between those threads. Below is my class which extends Thread in java:

```
public static class LoopThread extends Thread {
    int index;
    long numberOfRound;
    long numberOfSpins;

    public LoopThread(int index, long numberOfRound, long numberOfSpins) {
        this.index = index;
        this.numberOfRound = numberOfRound;
        this.numberOfSpins = numberOfSpins;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + index + " started for " + numberOfRound + " rounds and " + numberOfSpins + " spins");
        for(long i = 0; i < numberOfRound; i++) {
            for(long j = 0; j < numberOfSpins; j++) {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread " + index + " ended");
    }
```

The weird thing is when I first wrote this piece of code, it was almost scaling linearly until 8 threads. However, it was taking more time with 9 threads and the increase was small after 9 threads although my machine has 16 hardware threads. In order to investigate the problem, I just changed the code in a simple way so I put a time information in the last line of the code like:

```
System.out.println("Thread " + index + " ended: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
```

This change suprisingly made my code more scalable. Since I can't see an obvious reason behind why this change caused this improvement, I tried again and again and here some results which I consistently see:

Before the change:

```
time passed for 8 threads and 1000000 rounds and 800000 spins is 63 seconds
time passed for 9 threads and 1000000 rounds and 800000 spins is 69 seconds
```

After the simple change:

```
time passed for 8 threads and 1000000 rounds and 800000 spins is 62 seconds
time passed for 9 threads and 1000000 rounds and 800000 spins is 56 seconds
```

Again, I can't see any obvious reason behind that and it seems very weird to me. Do you have any idea about why this is happening?

Thanks

Edit(the code which starts threads and times):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int numberOfThreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    long numberOfRounds = Long.parseLong(args[1]);
    long numberOfSpins = Long.parseLong(args[2]);
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];

    for( int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
        threads[i] = new LoopThread(i, numberOfRounds, (long) numberOfSpins/numberOfThreads);
        threads[i].start();
    }

    for(Thread t: threads) {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println("time passed for " + numberOfThreads + " threads and " + numberOfRounds + " rounds and " + numberOfSpins + " spins is " + endTime/1000 + " seconds");
}
```

Comment: Post the code/method that starts the threads and times the task completion.

Comment: Sure, please check my edit. Thanks

Comment: Does your machine have hyper-threading? You probably just have 8 real CPU cores, so you wont really see any improvement past 8 threads for simple CPU bound benchmarks like this.

Comment: Yes, it has hyper-threading but we saw almost 16x improvement with a similar C++ benchmark with 16 threads. Also, I see an improvement around 14.5x after the change which I mentioned, previously it was around 11x before the change. I don't know how this change created a more scalable code if it does.

Comment: I don't really want to get into the detail of a proper answer, but im guessing the issue you are seeing is somehow related to the JIT compiler, if the compiler fully optimised this code it would take 0ms to run, since nothing actually happens in the loop. Clearly that is not exactly what is happening, but to really investigate it, you should use the JMH benchmark framework and enable debugging to look at the machine code that the JVM in generating in each case.

Comment: It’s strange that the JVM doesn’t optimize away that empty loop. But on my machine, inserting `System.currentTimeMillis()` makes no difference in the behavior (besides printing that number).

Comment: Thanks for checking. I am getting different performance results still. I tried to keep the time in a variable without printing and use it in a dummy if statement to prevent compiler optimization. It makes no difference and gives the same results with the first version. However, when I just insert this variable into println and print the time, it becomes more scalable and performs better.